# Did my contractor waterproof my new shower properly?

Tags: shower, waterproofing

Did my contractor water proof my new shower correctly? Here is the process I observed.

- vapor barrier cloth applied to walls and floor
- layer of mud on the floor.
- rubber/PVC membrane, thick gray sheet on the floor with all the corners sealed. This was also added to the niches
- Concrete board was put on the three walls.
- mortar applied to seams
- another layer of mud on top of the gray membrane with the final slope
- green/blue stuff painted onto concrete board. I’m guessing a water proof membrane. Not sure the brand. It was teal blue in the paint tray not very thick looking on the rough concrete board
- then concrete board was installed on the curb, mortar applied, and the same blue stuff applied. There are gaps in the corners of the concrete board and at the bottom above the mud floor.

The blue waterproofing was not applied to the concrete floor. And it is not seamless in all the joints.

Addition was all permitted but I didn’t hear anything about an inspector coming to check the shower.

- Should it be continuous providing no way for water to get through?
- Should it be applied to the floor?
- Anything else sounds wrong with this shower?
- Is there anything I need to do to make sure it’s right?

I hired them to do the shower before I was not confident in the water proofing of it. But not sure if they did it right.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add pictures using the button that looks like the moon and mountains ... do not post a link like you did

Comment: "There are gaps in the corners of the concrete board and at the bottom above the mud floor" You may want to take a close up of one or two of these gaps and tell us where in the overall picture they are. I don't see any from the images you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a correct installation, but the devil is in the details. The teal blue stuff sounds like AquaDefense waterproof membrane. It's common practice to "shingle" waterproofed walls over the pan liner, where the pan liner waterproofs the floor. It's common to bury the ends of the waterproofed walls in the final slope's dry pack so that the outward pressure restrains the walls and avoids fasteners down low that would puncture the pan liner. Alternatively it's common to stop the waterproofed walls 1/2" to 1" above the floor to prevent water from wicking up behind the surface layer of waterproof membrane.

The most common mistakes that cause major issues are pan liner punctures, cuts at pan liner corner folds, or a bad seal between the drain and the pan liner. If you have an image of the floor just before the final slope was done, that would be the place to look for problems.